# invalid_scope error in access token for client credential flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, identityserver4

I am getting invalid_scope error in access token request for client credential flow. The error log states that "cannot request OpenID scopes in client credentials flow". I haven't requested for the open id scope. I don't know from where it came from. I need to generate access token using client credential flow.

**Issue / Steps to reproduce the problem**

**API Resource definition.**

```
public IEnumerable GetApiResources()
{
    return new List {
        new ApiResource
        {
            Name = "WidgetApi",
            DisplayName = "Widget Management API",
            Description = "Widget Management API Resource Access",
            ApiSecrets = new List { new Secret("scopeSecret".Sha256()) },
            Scopes = new List {
                new Scope("WidgetApi.Read"),
                new Scope("WidgetApi.Write")
            }
        }
     };
}
```

**Client Definition;**

```
return new List
{
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "WidgetApi Client Id",
        ClientName = "WidgetApi Client credential",
        RequireConsent = false,
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret( clientSecret.Sha256())
        },
       // scopes that client has access to
       AllowedScopes = { "WidgetApi.Read", "WidgetApi.Write"},
       AccessTokenLifetime = 3600
   };
}
```

**Access token request body (key - value) using postman**

```
grant_type  client_credentials
response_type  id_token
scope  WidgetApi.Read WidgetApi.Write
client_secret  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
client_id  WidgetApiClientId
```

**Relevant parts of the log file**

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection[4]
Closing connection to database 'IdentityServer4Db' on server 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'.
dbug: IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore[0]
Found PssUserMgtApi.Read, PssUserMgtApi.Write API scopes in database
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cannot request OpenID scopes in client credentials flow
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]

{
        "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ClientName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "GrantType": "client_credentials",
        "Scopes": "xxxxxxxxxx.Read xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Write",
        "Raw": {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "response_type": "id_token",
            "scope": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.Read xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Write",
            "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
 }

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Request finished in 5292.2873ms 400 application/json
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
Connection id "0HL51IVGKG792" completed keep alive response.
```

Comment: It looks like your client_id is "WidgetApi Client Id", but in the postman you have "WidgetApiClientId"...

Comment: @MiguelDomingues That should have resulted in Invalid Client error.

Comment: Could it be that you've registered ```WidgetApi.Read``` and  ```WidgetApi.Write``` as IdentityResource instead of ApiResource? You will also still get an error asking for id_token for client_credentials flow. You should ask for "token" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no user tagged in a client credential flow, normally, client credential is not intended to have a scope tagged to it, and many frameworks doesnt support it.

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/ says :

**scope (optional)** :
Your service can support different scopes for the client credentials grant. ***In practice, not many services actually support this.***

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your client credential details are correct or not. You can also find this simple step by step explanation to configure client credential flow using this [link](http://java-codez.blogspot.com/2018/06/server-to-server-communication-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question already contains the answer:

> grant_type  client_credentials 
>   **response_type  id_token** 
>   scope WidgetApi.Read WidgetApi.Write 
>   client_secret  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
>   client_id  WidgetApiClientId

The request of `client_credentials` type should be processed at `token` endpoint and must not require `id_token` as the flow is non-interactive. The redundant parameter is breaking the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error with IdentityServer4 2.1.3, but not with IdentityServer4 2.3.2. It seems, from the GitHub issues for the project, that it was fixed in 2.3:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2295#issuecomment-405164127

Answer (score -1):

If you have this problem, just remove the 'openid' scope for a given client in the database in ClientScopes.